AWS S3 - MethodNotAllowed against this resource
I'm trying to call putObject using boto3 (Python) for the following bucket/key: "embeddings/soap".
When I attempt to do so, I get the error: An error occurred (MethodNotAllowed) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified method is not allowed against this resource
The same call works for similar words like 'soapcase', 'soap stand', etc. Is this a reserved key that isn't supposed to be used? I don't see any similar questions or documentations regarding this.

Your key is soap or soap.?

I edited the question for clarity @pierpy

AWS provides a depricated SOAP API, as a result, the key "soap" and prefix "soap/" are not allowed in virtual host style requests.

Please show us some minimal example code so we can reproduce your situation.
